# Actuator Refresh is giving 404 error for springboot 2.2.7

Tags: spring-boot, refresh, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to use actuator refresh endpoint using springboot 2.2.7. But I'm facing 404 error.

**My endpoint which is a POST call**

http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh

**Response:**

{
"timestamp": "2020-11-25T11:50:01.172+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/actuator/refresh"
}

Can someone please help me out regarding the same ? Stuck over here for almost half a day.

Will this actuator refresh works only for the spring cloud ? or can be used for any bean configuration refresh without the pod restart ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to install curl-7.76.0-win64-mingw
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh"